# What can be a nic name that should be available in pokemon go

Tags: pokemon-go

I have tried many but none is available .

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.random.org/strings/ and generate a random 30 character string with only the allowed characters and pretty much for sure it'll be allowed. If you're not interested in that I recommend what ever username you would with a lot of numbers at the end

Comment: If you want something more readable/easier to remember generate some random words at http://www.randomwordgenerator.com